# How can I combine destructuring assignment and optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining

I have a TypeScript interface with some optional fields and a variable of that type:

```
interface Foo {
    config?: {
        longFieldName?: string;
    }
}

declare let f: Foo;
```

I'd like to put `longFieldName` in a variable of the same name.

If `config` weren't optional, I'd use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to do this without repeating `longFieldName`. But it is, so I get a type error:

```
const { longFieldName } = f.config;
     // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~  Property 'longFieldName' does not exist on type '{ longFieldName?: string | undefined; } | undefined'.
```

I can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to concisely handle the `undefined` case:

```
const longFieldName = f?.config.longFieldName;  // OK, type is string | undefined
```

But now I have to repeat `longFieldName`.

Can I have my cake and eat it, too? Can I use optional chaining to handle the `undefined` case without repeating `longFieldName`? If not, what is the most concise/idiomatic workaround? See [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHILogzADmA-AFw76EMA2J5qwEjAJgHJwC2EGsgDOYKKHIBuegQC+uebk4QEjOFBSMIYZDFoZ003HgbEQo5MxCt2XXgOQBeXQDozZKi6s2OPfhEkCAHog5HQAawAaZAAjAFcdDQAHbWAwYAA3CAVcYxkiEgtsSxY2X3sUWSdXdwppBgaQ5AA-VoIABSh0FKgwAE9kAHJvMrt-QeROdAhhZBB0HQgAD2ALEmR+lKHikds-ASFRcWtkAB9kOJBlMhAITkCq88vr0DvBlxy8hiaAdXQocLCQBkBLEEnMFsg4LNiHwkogdFDkAB3NIACzCSXSJDgjCIqLgoAkH1MhR0O1KewqyCqzhgbhIHjO52wsmksiAA).

Comment: Currently is out of scope for ecma t39: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/74

Answer (score 50):

Use [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to get a fallback value (empty object) if the `f?.config` expression evaluate to `undefined`:

```
const { longFieldName } = f?.config || {};
```

Comment: That's the workaround. But is there something more akin to optional chaining? (I don't think you want the `...` before `longFieldName`.)

Comment: The `...` was redundant. As far as I know, optional chaining doesn't handle the fallback. The `...` was a leftover from another solution  - spread `f?.config` into an object `{ ...f?.config }`. If the chaining evaluates to `undefined` or `null`, they will be ignored by the spread.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref2.longFieldName')`.

Comment: For one property only on right side, this can be done too: `const { longFieldName = "" } = f ?? {}`, with optional (as I inserted) fallback value

Comment: This is what I usually do, but it bothers me and I wish ECMA could adopt `const { longFieldName } = f?.config?;`
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/74

Comment: This workaround will not work when you are destructuring more than one level deep. For instance, `const {longFieldName: {subField}} = f?.config || {} // Uncaught TypeError`. See the better answer by @wayne-li.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the default values.

```js
const Foo = {}
const { config: { longFieldName = "" } = {} } = Foo
console.log(longFieldName) //''
```

Comment: This does work if `config` is missing, but if you add another intermediate level that is also missing it will not work.

Comment: @TomBoutell this does work with intermediate levels. You just have to set their default as well with `= {}`. For instance: `let {config: {longFieldName: {subField = 123} = {}} = {}} = {}`